# VBA in Excel using If, Copy&Paste

Tags: vba, if-statement, copy

I am a very beginner in VBA. I would like to automatically copy and paste if a certain condition is met.
If Row G is "N" then copy from Range(Cells(Row+1,"h"), Cells(Row,"bg")) and paste to Range(Cells(Row+1,"h"), Cells(Row,"bg")) and add "Data substituted" in the substituted Row "bh".
There are codes I've been made so far, '13' runtime error occurs whenever I implemented the code below. I am very lost please help me! Thank you in advance.

```
Sub Sbustitute()

    Dim nRows As Long, LastRow As Long, Row As Long, Column As Range, Color As Long
    nRows = 2
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
      For Row = LastRow To nRows Step -1
        Set Cell = Cells(Row, "g")
        If Cell = "N" Then
            Range(Cells(Row + 1, "h"), Cells(Row + 1, "bg")).Copy Range(Cells(Row, "h"), Cells(Row, "bg"))
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Cells(Row, "bh") = "Data substituted" 
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: In your code, the `ActiveSheet.Paste` instruction is clearly unnecessary, because before using it to copy data to the clipboard, which does not happen, and its presence causes error 1004 - method Paste of class Worksheet completed incorrectly. When it is removed, the code works fine. The type mismatch error (13) could not be reproduced.

Comment: `Row` is a property of the `Range` object - you shouldn't use predeclared names as variable names.

Comment: @Samuel Everson Thank you for the anwser but I don't fully understand.

Comment: @ Samuel Everson Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following is what you are after.  Rather than `Range.Copy`, this version assigns the Value between the two Ranges.

```
    Sub Substitute()
        Dim nRows As Long, LastRow As Long, currentRow As Long, Column As Range, Color As Long

        nRows = 2
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
        For currentRow = LastRow To nRows Step -1
            Set Cell = Cells(currentRow , "g")
            If Cell = "N" Then
                Range(Cells(currentRow + 1, "h"), Cells(currentRow + 1, "bg")).Value = Range(Cells(currentRow , "h"), Cells(currentRow , "bg")).Value
                Cells(currentRow, "bh") = "Data substituted"
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```